# Unattached intersecting lines in Dot/Graphviz

Tags: graphviz, dot

this may be a dumb question but is it possible to add unattached intersecting lines in graphviz/dot? I'm currently trying to add trust boundries to my architectural graph, which I want to represent as perpendicular dashed lines that intersect the relevant arrows, like so (example knocked up using graphics package):

[image]

I've searched on here and on the net, but can't find the answer. It seems Dot is rigidly based on the flow of nodes, which might make sense but leaves me with a problem! At the moment I'm designating each trust boundry as a boxed area, but it looks unsightly.

Thanks in advance for your comments.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, @Tim Biegeleisen

Comment: No worries, I used GraphViz a bit many years ago when I was doing data mining.  It doesn't get great coverage here on SO, but I thought the edit would help.

Answer (score 1):

```
digraph {
    boundary [shape=underline height=0 style=dashed color=orange label=""]
    a -> b
    b -> boundary [dir=none]
    boundary -> c -> d
}
```

gives

[image]

Comment: Thanks Stefan I really appreciate that